# VBA insert a formula to existing cell

Tags: vba, excel

Cell A1 refers to Cell A5, which has a value of 5.5. I want to insert say a round function to Cell A1 that reads =round(A5,). I tried the following code below but it's not working as I intend it to.

```
Sub roundmacro()
   Dim n As String
   n = Range("A1").Value 'returns the value but I need reference from that range object instead  
   Range("A1").Formula = "=round(" & n & ",)"
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have n Dim'd as a string...it should be a number.  Plus you have assigned n the value of A1 not A5.

Comment: No that's not the issue.

Comment: It is if you want to round the value of A5, but you assigned it the value of A1

Comment: I need to indirectly round the value of A5. If i want to round A5 directly I can easily manipulate my code already.

Comment: If your question is trying to say that you want to change a formula from, say, `=A5` and make it `=ROUND(A5,)` instead then this question is a "duplicate" of [Insert Round function into current cell using VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8156109/6535336)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=Round(" & Mid(Range("A1").Formula, 2) & ",)"
```

This turns any existing formula into a `rounding` of that formula. So if the initial formula was `=A5`, the new formula becomes `=Round(A5,)`.

p.s. Works for any initial formula that returns a number (you cannot round a string, naturally).

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks A.S.H and everyone for your input.

Answer (score 2):

So you want the formula in A1 to show "A5" in it?

```
Range("A1") = "=Round(A5,)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be better to do the calculation in VBA, like this:

```
Sub formulas()

Range("A1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(Range("A5").Value, 0) ' You can put any formula after the 'Application.WorksheetFunction.'

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me, A1 = 6

```
Sub roundmacro()
   Dim n As String
   n = Range("A5").Value
   Range("A1").Formula = "=round(" & n & ",)"
End Sub
```

Comment: Pokemon, I'm looking for a code that "knows" range("A1") is referring to "A5", and hence giving me =round(A5,) in range("A1").

Comment: @user7433793 from my understanding, you are asking "I want to insert say a round function to Cell A1 that reads =round(A5,)." this does exactly what you ask if not please clarify in your post. "=round(" & n & ",)" = round(A5,)